# Concurrent bulk insert statements on transactional table with index

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We have a smallish, 40k rows, (thus far) transactional table with an index enabled on a single column. This index is extremely valuable to us as the reads to the table tend to be quite frequent.

At certain times, multiple bulk insert statements are performed on this transactional table, quite often 100s of mini bulk inserts (< 50 rows) in say an hour or two. Then it might lie idle for a while. Whilst each individual insert tends to work quite well, these concurrent INSERT statements tend to break (i.e. fail) after a while and won't work unless we restart the instance.

Is this because of the index? How can we work around that limitation? Is cursor.executemany preferable over cursor.execute in this case? Would sending these INSERT queries to a task queue make a difference?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using cloud SQL or the datatore, I assume the former but you should be explicit .

Answer (score 0):

What's the symptom of failure? Any error messages?
Could you check the innodb monitor status when it happens? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html